# in wordpress, how do I know what page is current?

Tags: wordpress

in wordpress, how do I know what page is current?
I have 5 pages that are my header menu bar, I want to CSS the current (open page) so user knows whats page they are on. Is there a way of doing this?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the is_page() function. You can use the page id, name or slug as an argument.

Examples:

```
<a href="#" <?php if(is_page(42)) echo 'class="active"'?>>Page 42</a>
<a href="#" <?php if(is_page('About Us')) echo 'class="active"'?>>About Us</a>
<a href="#" <?php if(is_page('our-friends')) echo 'class="active"'?>>Our Friends</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

using CSS, you can style the current page of WordPress.

CSS:

```
li.current_page_item a {
   color: red;
}
```

this WordPress Codex page may explain the whole process better: http://codex.wordpress.org/Dynamic_Menu_Highlighting